# Many URLs with trailing double slash?

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console

I have to check a wordpress site in Google Search Console (GSC) to find crawling problems.

Now I've seen in GSC that about 40 pages are excluded because they are redirects. The redirect is caused by a trailing double slash like `http://example.com//folder1/pag1e/` (// always directly after the domain). The page `http://example.com/folder1/page1/`is indexed as well and without error.

I'm just wondering from where this double-slashed version of the URL comes from? Wordpress misconfiguration somehow?

Can I remove these URLs from GSC somehow?

Best regards,LEx

Answer (score 1):

Please check your settings-> Permalink. It should be set post name. And if it is not working then check .htaccess for redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Run these SQL statements. You only have to go up to the double slash, it won't affect 
   non double slash URLS or the content after the double slash.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl//', 
'http://www.newurl/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl//','http://www.newurl/');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl//', 
'http://www.newurl/');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =  
replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl//','http://www.newurl/');
```

Comment: Related, if the OP (or anyone in the future) is comfortable with the CLI, I encourage them to check out [WordPress's official CLI tool](https://wp-cli.org/). With that you can perform a database-wide find and replace. For instance, `wp search-replace "http://example.com//" "http://example.com/" --recurse-objects --all-tables --dry-run`. This command won't actually change anything, but will tell you how many things it could change. Just remove the `--dry-run` parameter to actually run it.